# Weighted Adjusted R2

Tags: regression, r-squared

I understand the r2 metric, being 1- (rss /tss)
where rss = sum of squared residuals
and tss = total sum of squares

I understand how to weight this, such as when each row is a population, and some populations have a large number of samples and some have few (or some rows are just more important).  If we have a weight for each row, we just multiply both the error and difference from the mean when we do our sums.

I also understand how to do an adjusted r2, 1 - ((1 - r2)(n - 1) / (n - k - 1))
where n is the number of rows and k is the number of columns.  I understand this is to control for the number of variables, since adding information can never make our standard r2 worse even if the information is worthless.

Can I combine both of these?  E.g. both weight my rows and adjust for the number of columns?  Intuitively, this seems to work.  But I can't find this in any of my textbooks, and I can't find any real world examples either.

If this is valid, is it a well known technique?  If I use it in a research paper, am I going to be questioned or outright rejected for not citing where it came from?